# Using java interfaces to narrow the classes public interface

Tags: java, design, interfaces

There is a lot of content on the web discussing if it is worth defining an interface if only one class implements it. The answers are mostly either *"Yes, because you probably need to mock it anyways"* or *"No, I strongly believe in YAGNI"*.

But what about narrowing the classes public interface?

Example:

```
public interface Picture {
    public Dimension getSize();
    public void resize(Dimension d);
    // Some methods to retrieve byte data, etc
}

public class PictureImpl implements Picture {
    // Implement inherited methods
    public void setResizeStrategy(ResizeStrategy rs) { ... }
}
```

I intentionally do not add the `setResizeStrategy(..)` method to my interface, because i don't want other classes that accept a `Picture` object to change the strategy for resizing (think of linear upscaling vs using a technique such as antialiasing).

I essentially narrow the public interface of PictureImpl for the rest of my program, since it only uses the `Picture` interface (following the programming to an interface, not an implementation method).

I can then hide the actual `PictureImpl` construction in some kind of creating container, like a factory:

```
public class PictureFactory {
    public Picture createPicture() {
        PictureImpl p = new PictureImpl();
        // Search for a library that can resize pictures
        // If a library is found that we can support return the corresponding strategy
        // If no library is found, use our self coded linear upscale strategy
        ResizeStrategy strat = ResizeStrategyResolver.findBestStrategyAvailable();
        p.setResizeStrategy(strat);
        return p;
    }
}
```

Is this a valid use case for interfaces, or am i misusing the technology?

**Note:** I know that one could argue that changing the strategy during runtime might be a desired feature. I couldn't come up with a better example on the spot. I hope you get the point i am trying to make.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using interfaces as part of encapsulation](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/230479/using-interfaces-as-part-of-encapsulation)

Comment: The question is really quite similar to mine, but since it only has downvoted answers of which none is accepted i would like a better answer if possible :)

Comment: Does the technique you're asking about effectively solve a problem you're having in a real-world application?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The "picture" example might not be the best. Consider the Repository Pattern. You create interfaces for your repositories to allow for easy mocking. Is it a good practice to split these interfaces up on, say, read-only behavior versus read/write behavior? That would be a similar example to illustrate this question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: To be honest, I'm not a big fan of mocking and the proliferation of interfaces to support said mocking, *unless it is being done to generalize an operation or establish an external API, certainly not solely to facilitate testing.*  I'd rather make API's that can be tested without extensive mocking. Isn't that kinda the whole point of TDD, to force you to write code in such a way that it is easily testable?

Comment: @Greg That is a way better example than mine. I program an library where the user is supposed to use a `DataReceiver` object. The interface only provides one method named `getNextDataSet()`. The implementation has a lot more setup/configuration methods. But since i provide Service Classes that return a pre-configured `DataReceiver` object i don't see the point in making that part of the implementation interface visible to them.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Unless the code under test needs to hit a database, file system, or other outside resource that the programmer doesn't have control over. Then you need interfaces for the purpose of mocking.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Of course.  But then you're establishing an external API, aren't you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That is correct. You are establishing an external API. Sometimes the benefits of better testability outweigh the drawbacks of maintaining an external API.